# c# team foundation point version control server to mapped project

Tags: c#, tfs

So in my code I have this as the setup for accessing the server item.
`var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://samplerepo:8080/tfs_proj/WindowsMain"), new UICredentialsProvider());
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            VersionControlServer vsStore = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();`

However when I want to create a workspace based on this server I can't. The reason is that WindowsMain isn't mapped to a local folder. However WindowsMain/MainProject is mapped to a local folder. So how can I create a workspace that is mapped to MainProject. Seeing as I cannot connect to WindowsMain/MainProject just WindowsMain since the way server connections are done with team foundation.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Claudius trying to create a workspace that corresponds to the local folder so that I can compare the workspace version to the server version and figure out if the local solution is the same version as the server

Comment: and you are talking about WindowsMain/MainProject

Comment: Yes, The remote folder is $/MainProject and the local is C:/MainProject but I am having difficulty comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code updates all files in given project. if you want to compare it could be easily modified:

```
private static void GetLatest(string username, string password, string path_to_download,
          string tf_src_path)
{

    Uri collectionUri = new Uri(PathConstants.uri);
    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(PathConstants.uri), credential);
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    VersionControlServer vc = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    foreach (Workspace workspace in vc.QueryWorkspaces(null, null, System.Environment.MachineName))
        {
            foreach (WorkingFolder folder in workspace.Folders)
            {
            ItemSpec itemSpec = new ItemSpec(folder.ServerItem,  RecursionType.Full);
            ItemSpec[] specs = new ItemSpec[] { itemSpec };
            ExtendedItem[][] extendedItems = workspace.GetExtendedItems(specs, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File);
            ExtendedItem[] extendedItem = extendedItems[0];
                foreach (var item in extendedItem)
                {
                    if (item.VersionLocal != item.VersionLatest)
                    {
                        vc.DownloadFile(item.SourceServerItem, item.LocalItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you can replace:
`vc.DownloadFile(item.SourceServerItem, item.LocalItem);`

with `Console.WriteLine(item.LocalItem +": needs updating");`

Comment: Even though I am out of sync with the server it is not showing htat items need updating. Any guess as to why that could be?

Comment: do you get to the for each loop? debug it or place console writeline before if  statement

Comment: or add system `diagnostics namespace` and use `debug.writeline(item.LocalItem +": needs updating");`

Comment: it will be in the output window, when you debug it